# Когда ставить точку после цитаты со знаком внутри кавычек?

Tags: пунктуация, цитата, цитирование, оформление-цитат

> Б. Л. Пастернак подчеркивал: «Самое ясное, запоминающееся и важное в
>   искусстве есть его возникновенье, и лучшие произведенья мира,
>   повествуя о наиразличнейшем, на самом деле рассказывают о своем
>   рожденьи» (Пастернак 2000, 207).
>
> б) ставят точку, если цитата не является самостоятельным предложением,
>   а выступает как часть придаточного (даже если перед закрывающими
>   кавычками стоит многоточие, вопросительный или восклицательный знак):
>
> Б. Л. Пастернак подчеркивал, что «самое ясное, запоминающееся и важное
>   в искусстве есть его возникновенье...».

Разве вот эта цитата сверху является частью придаточного предложения?

> Жорж Санд писала: "Книга всегда была для меня советницей, утешительницей, красноречивой
>   и спокойной, и я не хотела исчерпать ее благ, храня их для наиболее
>   важных случаев"

И ставить ли точку в моём случае снизу?

> Вспомним цитату Жорж Санд: ”Книга всегда была для меня советницей,
>   утешительницей...”.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно написать так.

1. Полная цитата оформлена как прямая речь, поэтому после закрывающих кавычек **ставится точка.**

Жорж Санд писала: «Книга всегда была для меня советницей, утешительницей, красноречивой и спокойной, и я не хотела исчерпать ее благ, храня их для наиболее важных случаев».

2. Предложение также оформлено как прямая речь, но внутри кавычек находится неполная цитата. В этом случае ставится многоточие, после закрывающих кавычек **точки нет.**

Вспомним цитату Жорж Санд: «Книга всегда была для меня советницей, утешительницей...»

*В. Г. Белинский писал: «В “Онегине” все части органически сочленены…»*

[Многоточие при цитатах](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=163) (Розенталь)

**Дополнение** (попробуем по-другому)

1. Цитаты заключаются в кавычки и оформляются знаками препинания так же, как прямая речь. [с двоеточием; после открывающей кавычки с большой буквы]

*У М. Алигер есть **строки: «Человеку** надо очень мало, чтобы счастье выросло в полный рост».*

2. Если цитата не является самостоятельным предложением (то есть включена в авторское предложение на правах его компонента) и заканчивается многоточием, то после закрывающих кавычек ставится точка, относящаяся ко всему предложению в целом. [без прямой речи, без двоеточия; после открывающей кавычки с маленькой буквы]

*Искандер заметил, **что «мудрость** — это ум, настоянный на совести...».*

[Знаки препинания при цитатах](https://orfhographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137) (Лопатин)

Comment: так как она неполная вроде-бы наоборот нужно ставить точку после неё. "ставят точку, если цитата не является самостоятельным предложением, а выступает как часть придаточного (даже если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит многоточие, вопросительный или восклицательный знак)". Хотя она же не часть придаточного предложения. Но что-то сложно

Comment: Вы путаете два понятия: цитата и предложение. В Ваших примерах НЕТ никаких придаточных предложений. Есть цитаты (полная и неполная), которые сами по себе являются самостоятельными предложениями. Предложение с прямой речью состоит из двух: первое — слова автора, второе — чьи-то слова (собственно цитата).

Comment: то есть если в моём придаточном предложении есть чья-то цитата, то после неё я обязан ставить точку в любом случае?

Comment: Еще раз: у Вас (в Ваших примерах) **нет** придаточных предложений. Придаточное предложение — это **часть** сложноподчиненного предложения, например, такого (с союзом "что"): _М. В. Ломоносов писал, **что** «красота, великолепие, сила и богатство российского языка явствует довольно из книг, в прошлые века писанных…»._ В этом случае цитата не является самостоятельным предложением, после нее ставится точка. Ваши же предложения оформлены как прямая речь — с двоеточием.